# How do I get back an ActiveRecord instead of an ActiveRecord relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, ruby-on-rails-5

Using Rails 5.  How do I get an ActiveRecord instead of an ActiveRecord relation?  I ahve the below model

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country

    ...
  def self.cached_find_us_state_by_name(name)
    Rails.cache.fetch("#{name.upcase} US") do
      find_us_state_by_name(name)
    end
  end

  # Look up a US state by its full name 
  def self.find_us_state_by_name(name)
    search_criteria = ["upper(states.name) = ? "]
    search_criteria.push( "states.country_id = countries.id " ) 
    search_criteria.push( "countries.iso = 'US' " ) 

    results = State.joins(:country).where( search_criteria.join(' and '),
                                           name.upcase) 
  end
```

but when I lookup an item using the methods, waht I get back is an ActiveReocrd relation ...

```
2.4.0 :004 >  State.cached_find_us_state_by_name('Ohio')
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<State id: 3538, name: "Ohio", country_id: 233, iso: "OH">]>
```

This is cauisng problems later on, specifically ...

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: State(#70288305660760) expected, got State::ActiveRecord_Relation(#70288290686360)
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:221:in `raise_on_type_mismatch!'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:12:in `replace'
```

**Edit:** Per the suggestion given, I changed my methods to

```
  def self.cached_find_us_state_by_name(name)
    Rails.cache.fetch("#{name.upcase} US") do
      find_us_state_by_name(name)
    end
  end

  # Look up a US state by its full name 
  def self.find_us_state_by_name(name)
    search_criteria = ["upper(states.name) = ? "]
    search_criteria.push( "states.country_id = countries.id " ) 
    search_criteria.push( "countries.iso = 'US' " ) 

    results = State.joins(:country).where( search_criteria.join(' and '),
                                           name.upcase).take  
  end
```

but alas, I still get an ActiveRecord::Relation

```
2.4.0 :011 > State.cached_find_us_state_by_name('Ohio')
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<State id: 3538, name: "Ohio", country_id: 233, iso: "OH">]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `find_by` instead of `where` - the source code for this is  simple:

```
def find_by(*args)
  where(*args).take
end
```

Another way is to call `.first` or `[0]` but if your `where` has a lot of records this will be slow since it's loading them all into memory before selecting the first. If use `limit(1)` then these methods will be acceptably fast.

Comment: I edited my question to show what happend when I tried your suggestion.  Just add ".take"?  Its not working.

Comment: Nvm, it did work -- the data was being cached but when I quit the console and reloaded it ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to get the `ActiveRecord` object from an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.The result of the call to

```
results = State.joins(:country).where( search_criteria.join(' and '),
                                       name.upcase)
```

returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. This is always the case when you use the `where` clause in `ActiveRecord`. In order to get a specific `ActiveRecord` object, you could:

- use the `find_by` method which returns the first instance in the database that it finds. Note that this does not return all of the records matching the criteria. * For example, `User.find_by(first_name: "Mark")` will return an `ActiveRecord` object containing the first record with a first name of "Mark"
- Use the `first` method on the `ActiveRecord::Relation` collection. For example, `User.where(first_name: "Mark").first` does the same thing as the previous example.
- Lastly, you could write something like this:

  ```
  User.where(first_name: "Mark") do |u|
    puts u.last_name
  end
  ```

  This allows you to iterate through the `ActiveRecord::Relation` collection one record at a time. So for your example, it would look something like this:

  ```
  results.each do |res|
    # do stuff
  end
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Most of ActiveRecord methods returns ActiveRecord::Relations in order to provide a fluent API ( syntactically pleasing method chaining if you will ). I think this is a design decision. There are a few method that breaks this, such as `first` (which really is a call to `find_nth!(0)` ), `last` `to_a`, `to_sql` and some others.

So, the way I found "around" this is to use `.first` where I really intended to get one and only one result back, as Mark and maxple are suggesting. I also think its probably one of the only way to do so.

This : https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/603ebae2687a0b50fcf003cb830c57f82fb795b9/activerecord/lib/active_record/querying.rb

And this (to which Querying delegates most of it's methods): https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/603ebae2687a0b50fcf003cb830c57f82fb795b9/activerecord/lib/active_record/querying.rb

are probably worth skimming through.